# Terraform Elasticache subnet group subnet_ids asks for string in place of list

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elasticache

I think the title is speaking for itself, I'm using an elasticache module with a subnet group and it worked well until now, but today when I tried to check that everything was good, I got this error with my plan:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

on ../modules/cache/redis/main.tf line 3, in resource "aws_elasticache_subnet_group" "default":
   3:   subnet_ids = var.subnet_test_ids
    |----------------
    | var.subnet_test_ids is list of object with 3 elements

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_ids": incorrect set element type:
string required.
```

The code:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_subnet_group" "default" {
  name       = "${var.name_prefix}-redis-subnet-group"
  subnet_ids = var.subnet_test_ids
}
```

It follows the [documentation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/elasticache_subnet_group.html) and I can't seem to find something wrong, does someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you share the definition of `var.subnet_test_ids` as well as how you're providing it? The error says "list of object with 3 elements" which indicates that somehow the variable is of type `list(object)` rather than `list(string)`.

Comment: Hooo... I should have quit for today... It was the variable, I'm going to look in git to see when I made the change in the variable...